# Is it possible to change the data sheet because of the date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I would like to ask if it is possible to change the data source sheet  according to the month in the year. In last sheet I have a summary that takes thata from the last month. I would like to automatically gather the information from the month that is now. Is it possible?

Comment: Use the indirect function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the Indirect function you can easily grab data from a different location:
[image]

Changing the value in A2 will cause the total in B2 to change. Jan & Feb sheets in this example just have the day number in column A.

You could also use named ranges to accomplish the same results.
It gets a bit trickier if the data on the different month sheets isn't in the same location!

HTH

Comment: And if I want to make this automatically? For example i have  two columns, one contains dates and other values for each day. In the other sheet i would like to sum cells with the value for the day that was yesterday. Is it possible to make it with the formula?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but w/o seeing your setup providing an exact formula is not possible.

Comment: '='JAN2021'!M12:T13' This is my code for the cell, i would like when it will be february to automatically change the sheet from JAN2020 to FEB2020, the cell is in the same place. So the change would be to '='FEB2021'!M12:T13'

Comment: Mateusz, I'm sorry but I don't quite grasp your setup. Could you please post a sample worksheet or at least pictures of the sheet where you want the answer and one of the Monthly sheets showing the range M12:T13.

Comment: Ok, so meybe the photo will show it better 
"https://ibb.co/Jt9zfV9
I would like to be able to to get in the cell "current month" the amount from the sheet that has name from the month that is now nad automaticaly change sheets during the year Thanks & Regards for help